# Regex for 00408C followed by 6 unique characters in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create regex for macaddress which start with 00408C followed by 6 unique characters(small letters, big letters, digits).

For example: 00408c1a2b3 or 00408C1A2B3.

How the regex for that would look like in C#?

I think something like that but I do not know how the alphanumeric character is defined in c#.
`"00408[alphanumeric character]{6}"`

Comment: @L.B I know regex in Java well, in C# symbols are significally different.

Comment: @Yoda - `C# symbols are significally different` Not for something as standard as character classes - http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html

Answer (score 5):

There it is:

```
00408[Cc][a-zA-Z0-9]{6}
```

Comment: Does not work :/ :http://wklej.org/id/1236779/

It works without ^ in the beginning.

Comment: If something can be before it, so yes you have to avoid ^ at beginning. It is the same for $ at the end (if there can be something after it)

Answer (score 2):

If by "unique characters" you mean a character cannot be repeated, you should use this regex:

```
00408[Cc]([a-zA-Z0-9])((?!\1)[a-zA-Z0-9])((?!\1)(?!\2)[a-zA-Z0-9])((?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)[a-zA-Z0-9])((?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(?!\4)[a-zA-Z0-9])((?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3)(?!\4)(?!\5)[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

You can find an explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/mV6oY7.

Comment: +1 for taking the OP at face value.  Now, two problems, he has :-)